# IIS Server App Pool: set Identity custom account without password

Tags: iis, iis-7

When I am trying to set my windows account (not domain) as identity of IIS Server default app pool, I'm receving error

> The specified password is invalid. Enter a new password.

The windows account has not password and I don't want to set it. How to enable to specify identity without password? Thanks.